# React: Prevent large tree structure for re-rendering children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a tree/directory structured data with around 14k nodes.
I want to prevent all children of the tree from re-rendering since it takes a bit too long. A node can be expanded and minimized when clicking a button, which adds the id of the node to an `expanded` `Set` saved in Redux state. Currently, when adding a category to the Set the entire tree is re-rendered. How would I prevent this?

The data structure:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Category 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Category 1-1",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Category 2",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Category 2-1",
        "children": [
          ...children
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ... and so forth
]
```

I have a recursive `TreeTableBranch` component which renders its children recursively:

```
const TreeTableBranch: React.FC<Props> = ({
 node,
 level,
 onExpand
}) => {
  const expanded = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.categories.expanded);
  const shouldExpand = expanded.has(node.category.id);
  return (
    ...lots of divs for rendering a node
      <button onClick={onExpand}>Expand<Button/> 
       { shouldExpand &&
       node.children.map((v,i) => (
       <TreeTableBranch
          key={v.category.id}
          node={v}
          level={level + 1}
          onExpand={onExpand}
        />
     )}
  )
}
```

However, since the `expanded` list is modified, all children get re-rendered. I've tried to use `useMemo()` as follows:

```
const children = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      shouldExpand &&
      node.children.map((v, i) => (
        <TreeTableBranch
          key={`category-branch-${v.category.id}`}
          node={v}
          level={level + 1}
          onExpand={onExpand}
          onAddCategory={onAddCategory}
          onDeleteCategory={onDeleteCategory}
        />
      ))
    );
  }, [shouldExpand]);
```

However this does not work, probably because the `expanded` list is modified.

I've also tried to use `React.memo()` like this:

```
const areEqual = (prevProps: Props, nextProps: Props) => {
  return prevProps.shouldExpand === nextProps.shouldExpand;
};
```

But it does not stop the other children from re-rendering.

Any help or tips are appreciated!

Comment: `React.memo` maybe

Comment: @Sam I've tried it but without luck, added it to the description.

Comment: What happens if you don't pass `onExpand`, `onAddCategory`, `onDeleteCategory` functions and dispatch actions directly in child components?

Comment: No luck there, although I managed to fix this by flattening the tree using React.memo on both the parent and children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to prevent a re-render without changing the structure of the tree. I've flattened the tree to a list and ensured that the `TreeTableBranch` used React.memo like so: `export default React.memo(TreeTableBranch);` as @Sam mentioned without adding a comparsion function, as well as its parent. I also removed passing the `onExpand`, `onAddCategory` and `onDeleteCategory` function props as @glinda93 suggested, although I am not 100% sure if this fixed it.

Finally, I realized the initial render of the large tree still took too long, so with this flattened structure it was much easier to use `react-window` to virtualize the list.